# How to get a report that has all utm_campaign parameters in it?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, utm-parameters

When I go to create a segment in Google Analytics I do the following:

1. Click `New Segment`
2. Click `Traffic Sources`
3. Then in the `Campaign` box, I start typing a parameter name, and it starts displaying `utm_campaign` parameters that have been submitted to GA.

How do I get a full list of these, instead of just matching them in the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex match type ("matches regex") but you would need to supply some sort of string to match campaign names against, for example, if you wanted to match all campaign names that started with "sale", then you would use a string like

```
^sale.*
```

Comment: Oh neat I didn't know you could use a regex in there...